# Bitbucket pipeline with docker and mysql

Tags: mysql, django, docker, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to implement some CI/CD for a Django web using the bitbucket pipeline. The goal is: Test the Docker builds correctly and next run Django test.

But I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on \'127.0.0.1\' (111 "Connection refused")')
```

Here is the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`:

```
options:
  docker: true

definitions:
  services:
    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      variables:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: 'foo'
          MYSQL_USER: 'default'
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'default'
          MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'

  steps:
    - step: &test-docker
        name: "docker builds"
        services:
          - docker
          - mysql
        caches:
          - docker
        script:
          - export IMAGE_NAME=foo:$BITBUCKET_COMMIT
          - export CONTAINER_NAME=test-foo

          - docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME .
          - docker run -p 8080:8080 --name $CONTAINER_NAME --rm -d $IMAGE_NAME

          - docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME python /app/manage.py test tests --noinput
          - docker stop $CONTAINER_NAME

pipelines:
  default:
      - step: *test-docker
```

I already tried some solutions and workarounds like. Linking the ports from the services and the docker; using volumes; and test the Django outside docker. This one have more problems because it needs 2 DB (original and test) and a user with full access, and using the entrypoint didn't work.

Comment: For the record I think bitbucket updated how pipeline works and now this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The database address specified in your django application i.e., `127.0.0.1` only works if you have mysql running in you local system and not the container.

As you are using a docker image of mysql, it has it's own IP address and not 127.0.0.1.  You can use `docker inspect <container id>` to get the IP address.

check this in you django settings.py file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'foo',
        'USER': 'default',
        'PASSWORD': 'default',
        'HOST': <mysql_ip>, #this is 127.0.0.1 in your case 
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

If you are internally using docker services through `docker-compose`, you can simply access the mysql container using it's `service name` in the yml file.

Comment: Sorry, but I've already tried this. Setting in `settings.py`: `HOST: 127.0.0.1` and `PORT: 3306` and next use -p 3306:3306 to link the two mysql.

Comment: What is your HOST in settings.py?

Comment: copied from the project: `'HOST': '127.0.0.1'`

Comment: That is what I was talking about. You cannot use localhost/127.0.0.1 as your mysql in an image and not running in local. Go through my answer, get the IP of mysql and replace 127.0.0.1 with that.

Comment: Ah, okey I I misunderstood you. But how do I get this in the bitbucket pipeline?